# General term of a series

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the general term of the series:

$$( 1 + x + ... + x^{m-1} )^k$$

I am trying to implement the KZ filter and it requires the coefficients of the above series. Here, k and m are dependent on the specific case so they will vary and hence, we need to find the general term for the coefficients.

We tried using the binomial expansions and moving ahead from there, but that did not take us anywhere. So, how do I find the general term of this series in terms of k and m?

Comment: You have a geometric progression and what is inside the parentheses is equal to $\frac{x^m-1}{x-1}$

Answer (score 1):

If we write $$(1+x+...+x^{m-1})^k=\sum_{n=0}^{(m-1)k}a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
need to find $a_n$ where $a_n=0$ for $n>(m-1)k$
$$(1+x+...+x^{m-1})^k=\left(\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}\right)^k=(1-x^m)^k(1-x)^{-k}=$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(-x^m)^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+j-1}{j}x^j=$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{k+j-1}{j}x^{j-mi}=$$
$j-mi=n\Rightarrow j=n+mi$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{k+n+mi-1}{n+mi}x^{n}$$
finally we have
$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{k+n+mi-1}{k-i}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, but could you tell me why you have assumed the series till infinity in the first step? It is given that the series is till (m-1). Using your final result i am getting incorrect values for coefficients taking the example of m=3 and k=2.

Comment: @Pranav. My answer is edited.